# SQL task from job interview

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, firebird

I was recently on one job interview and one question was about databases which makes me problem for a bit.

This was task:

You are creating database scheme for bloging service where:

1. Every user has one blog
2. Every blog can have many different categories of blog posts
3. Every blog can have blog posts
4. Every post can be multiple categories

And questiones where:

1. Write select query containing 2 users with the most posts
2. Get a post which includes most categories

I have created database with datatables - *Users, Blogs, BlogCategory, Categories, Postcategory and Posts*

BlogCategory and Postcategory are relation tables mapping relation between blog/post and its category and I think this is correct database scheme.

And about these questions, I think that both will be some complicated queries with inner joins but so far I was not able to solve them. Any idea please?

I am trying in now in firebird db, because MS SQL server has problem installing ms sql management studio. Thing is that you have come up with your own tables with their columns and keys. For sure you will need User, blog, post, category table, next tables are up to you

Comment: Please post what you have tried. Having your table creation queries would help, too.

Comment: I think the specification is incomplete. I guess I wouldn't get the job :-(

Comment: If I had to use firebird, I would take a pass

Comment: But seriously post a sqlfiddle. We will take a look.

Comment: I  am trying in now in firebird db, because MS SQL server has problem installing ms sql management studio. Thing is that you have come up with your own tables with their columns and keys. For sure you will need User, blog, post, category table, next tables are up to you

Answer (score 1):

Pretty vague to say the least but pretty sure something like this should work.

```
select top 2 UserName
from Posts
group by UserName
order by count(*) desc

select top 1 PostID
from Posts p
join PostCategories pc on pc.PostID = p.PostID
group by p.PostID
order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: I am afraid it will not work at least in first case - the user name should be probably stored in Users table, not in the post table

Comment: I would agree. So make it a join to the Users table. As I said, this is incredibly vague and sadly both questions are basically the same thing which is a bit strange for an interview situation.